# How can I call function from some python sripts which names can change in another python script?

Tags: python

I have some python scripts in the directory. I want to call a function with specific name from each script. The problem is that amount and names of scripts can change.

So i can't just do this:

```py
import script1
import script2
import script3

f1 = script1.func()
f2 = script2.func()
f3 = script2.func()
```

I need something like this:

```py
import os

scripts = os.listdir("scriptsdir")

f = []
for script in scripts:
    import script
    f.append(script.func())
```

but unfortunately this code won't work

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking, it looks like you'd be better off doing this in a bash script

Comment: *Why* do the module names change? Figure that out, and you can find a way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [imp](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imp.html) module in order to achieve this.

An example would be: (At the moment I have only a Python 2.7 example)

```py
import imp
m = imp.load_source(name, filepath)
m.func()
```

I hope this can lead you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3 you can use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to do this.
Assuming your modules are all in an importable directory.

```
import os
from importlib import import_module
mod_files = [i.rstrip('.py') for i in os.listdir('scriptsdir') 
             if i.endswith('.py')]
modules = [import_module('scriptsdir.' + mod) for mod in mod_files]
f = [mod.func() for mod in modules]
```

Answer (score 1):

On that website you can find exactly what you need:
https://www.devdungeon.com/content/import-python-module-string-name
So your for loop should be something like this:

```
import importlib
for script_name in scripts:
    module = importlib.import_module(script_name)
    module.func()
```